# How to understand the spectrum of a C*-algebra?

Tags: c-star-algebras

I know that the spectrum of an element $x$ in a unital C*-algebra $A$ is defined as
$$\operatorname{Sp}_{A} x=\left\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\mid (x-\lambda\cdot1)\ \text{is not invertible}\right\}.$$

Reference materials I am reading all seem to assume that the notion of *spectrum of an element* extends naturally to the notion of *spectrum on a C*-algebra*.  Concretely, I am having issues understanding the idea behind the following two pieces of text.

> If $A$ is commutative, then $A\cong C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$, the spectrum is the range, and the spectral radius is the supremum norm.
>
> <sup>Rieffel, M. *208 C^*-algebras*, 2013</sup>
>
> ---
>
> Let $A$ be a commutative C*-algebra, $S$ its spectrum (which is a locally compact space), and $B$ the C*-algebra of continuous complex-valued functions on $S$ which vanish at infinity.  Then
>
> (i) Every character of $A$ is hermitian,
>   (ii) The Gelfand map is an isomorphism of the C*-algebra $A$ onto the C*-algebra $B$.
>
> <sup>Dixmier, J. *C*-Algebras*, 1977</sup>

I might be missing some (trivial) connections, so here are the questions:

1. What is the spectrum of a C*-algebra? How is it defined, and is it related to the spectrum of an element of a C*-algebra?
2. Why is $B=C(S)$ involved, why not continuous complex-valued functions on some other set than $S$?
3. If possible, how to intuitively understand:
   a. the spectrum $S$ of $A$,
   b. the isomorphism between $A$ and $C(S)$, which is also known as a Gelfand map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spectrum $\Omega(A)$ of a C$^*$-algebra $A$ is the set of characters, that is the nonzero $*$-homomorphisms $\varphi:A\to\mathbb C$. This set may be empty even in easy examples, like for instance when $A=M_n(\mathbb C)$, $n\geq2$.

When $A$ is commutative, though, we have the following nice result relating the two notions (spectrum of the algebra and spectrum of an element): for any $a\in A$, 
$$\tag{$*$}
\sigma(a)=\{\varphi(a):\ \varphi\in\Omega(A)\}\cup Z_A,
$$
where $Z_A=\varnothing$ if $A$ is unital, and $Z_A=\{0\}$ if $A$ is non-unital.

The relevance of the spectrum is not that much given by $(*)$, but rather by the Gelfand transform, which says that there is a natural isomorphism between the commutative C$^*$-algebra $A$ and $C(\Omega(A))$, where we consider the weak$^*$-topology in $\Omega(A)$. For the technicalities of the proof one uses the fact that there is a bijective correspondence between characters and maximal ideals via $\varphi\leftrightarrow\ker\varphi$.

Comment: For $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, if $\Omega(M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))=\varnothing$, then $\sigma(a)=\varnothing$ for all matrices $a\in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. How can square matrices have eigenvalues then?

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote: "When $A$ is **commutative**, though..."

Answer (score 1):

**The key idea is that the spectrum of a $C^*$-algebra means spectrum in the sense of a ring, and the spectrum of a ring *is* related to eigenvalue decomposition for a special choice of ring.**  Wikipedia has [a relatively good exposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_C*-algebra) of these topics, so here's what I took away from it.

Suppose $T$ is an operator on a n.v.s. $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$.  I'll remind you that $\mathbb{C}[T]$ is the ring of formal power series in $T$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, and then claim expect there to be some sort of decomposition (in the sense of isometric isomorphism) $$V\cong\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\sigma(T)}{\mathbb{C}[T]/(T-\lambda)^{m(\lambda)}}$$  This is certainly true in the finite-dimensional case — it's called the Chinese Remainder Theorem for f.g. modules over a PID.  In the infinite-dimensional case, we can get close with very few assumptions; if $V$ is Hilbert and $T$ normal, then there exists a projection-valued measure $\mu_T$ on $\sigma(T)$ such that $$T=\int_{\sigma(T)}{\lambda\,\mu_T(d\lambda)}$$ where the integral exists in a suitably weak topology.  If we interpret each "value" of the absolutely continuous part of $\mu_T$ as a subspace isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[T]/(T-\lambda)$, then we can see that all we've done is replace the direct sum with a more general method of knitting together n.v.ses.  For a reference on this, see [[1]](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/funcana.pdf); for the non-Hilbert case, see [[2]](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/bcp/bcp38/bcp3817.pdf) and maybe do a few Google searches.

Now, in each case (both finite-dimensional and infinite), there are no zero-divisors of $\mathbb{C}[T]/(T-\lambda)^{m(\lambda)}$ except nilpotents, so $(T-\lambda)$ is prime.  In algebraic geometry, a prime ideal corresponds to an irreducible variety (irreducible vanishing set of a bunch of polynomials).  This suggest we interpret the eigenvalues as algebraic varieties; endow them with the [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology) and study the spectrum of a operator as a topological space.

We can replace $\mathbb{C}[T]$ with an arbitrary commutative unital $\mathbb{C}$-algebra to obtain the [spectrum of a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring) — no problem.  The key picture now is that we are looking at $\mathbb{C}[T_1,T_2,\dots]$, and the spectrum describes the eigenvalues of all the mutually diagonalizable operators.

In the $C^*$-algebra case, the above *almost* goes through, but not quite.  Because $C^*$-algebras are, in general, not commutative, we need to use a generalization of a prime: an ideal is *primary* if it annihilates a simple left module.  This gives us extra copies of the same ideal, up to isomorphism in the category of $C^*$-algebras (unitary equivalence). So now we have to quotient out by that.

Putting it all together, we have the following definition.

> The *spectrum of a $C^*$-algebra* is quotient of the set of primary ideals with the Zariski topology by unitary equivalence.

**And now to a few specific questions.**

*Why is $S$ involved?* There's no point in using more points.  As I mentioned above, $S$ is already the "set of mutual eigenvalues for all the operators studied," so your operators will be simultaneously constant on subsets if you add more points.

*What is the Gelfand map?*  Each operator is uniquely determined by its action.  So look at all possible ways a $C^*$-algebra could act on a space — its representations.  Theoretically, there should be an isomorphism between the algebra and its relations.  For the special case most useful towards building intuition, look up [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality#Pontryagin_duality_and_the_Fourier_transform).

Comment: I'm currently down the math rabbit hole trying to comprehend your explanation. Will probably take some time.